# Inline debug (xtrace) in scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, debugging

Is there a way to force enable or disable debug (xtrace) per command line in scripts ?

In Windows Shell ("ms-dos") is an "@" which can prefix a command line, disabling that line to be showed if the echo (lets say debug) is enabled (echo on).

Consider xtrace on (set -x), but we could ommit its effect in some lines prefixing it lets say with "@". Like as:

```
set -x
@echo Listing...
ls
set +x
```

Output example:

```
Listing...
+ ls
file1
file2
```

Is something similar in shell scripts ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not aware of any shell that has such an operator. However, with most shells (ksh being the exception) you can silently toggle `xtrace` with:

```
{
  case $- in
    (*x*) set +x;;
    (*) set -x
  esac
} 2> /dev/null
```

So you could make it an alias:

```
alias 'xx={
  case $- in
    (*x*) set +x;;
    (*) set -x
  esac
} 2> /dev/null'
```

And use as:

```
set -x
echo traced
xx; echo not traced; xx
echo traced
set +x
```

Note that with bash, you need `shopt -s expand_aliases` for aliases to be expanded in non-interactive shells (like in scripts).

Comment: @Gilles, (re: edit) indeed pdksh and mksh R50 output `+ 2> /dev/null`, but  not R46 here for some reason.